# Is Maven text based tool like Ant?

Tags: spring, maven

I am new to Spring and I am looking for a solution which help me fill in the dependencies for Spring in my project. So I came across Maven as suggested by others in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824965/how-should-you-load-spring-related-jar-in-eclipse). I am trying to learn it.

I found it doesn't give easy way to integrate with Eclispe. Although the official site did give some hint on eclipse integration, it doesn't help much. Most of the hints from the site are commandline which should be execute in shell.

I've discovered that the Spring Tool Suite has integrated Maven in Eclipse for us. I tried to make a pom.xml to it, and found that I can build it with Maven:

[image]

I chose "install" and it completed successfully. But still there is a lot of red cross over the project:

[image]

What is it actually doing?

Here is my pom.xml, it has spring.core and spring.context:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.aj.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>certification</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>certification</name>

    <!-- Shared version number properties -->
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.aj.spring.MainClass</mainClass>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>argument1</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    <!-- Core utilities used by other modules. Define this if you use Spring 
        Utility APIs (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*) -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Expression Language (depends on spring-core) Define this if you use 
            Spring Expression APIs (org.springframework.expression.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core) Define 
            this if you use Spring Bean APIs (org.springframework.beans.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework (depends on spring-core, 
            spring-beans) Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs (org.springframework.aop.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Application Context (depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, 
            spring-beans) This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection 
            Container and is generally always defined -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Support for testing Spring applications with tools such as JUnit and 
            TestNG This artifact is generally always defined with a 'test' scope for 
            the integration testing framework and unit testing stubs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail, 
            Quartz, and Freemarker integration Define this if you need any of these integrations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Transaction Management Abstraction (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-aop, spring-context) Define this if you use Spring Transactions or 
            DAO Exception Hierarchy (org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JDBC Data Access Library (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, 
            spring-tx) Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API (org.springframework.jdbc.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Object-to-Relation-Mapping (ORM) integration with Hibernate, JPA, 
            and iBatis. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx) 
            Define this if you need ORM (org.springframework.orm.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Object-to-XML Mapping (OXM) abstraction and integration with JAXB, 
            JiBX, Castor, XStream, and XML Beans. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-context) Define this if you need OXM (org.springframework.oxm.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and 
            Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context) 
            Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another 
            web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC for Servlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Servlet 
            Container such as Apache Tomcat (org.springframework.web.servlet.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC for Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Portlet 
            Container (org.springframework.web.portlet.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: The project you've circled looks that you don't follow the Maven conventions for source code (src/main/java) which causes the first problem. Furthermore without the pom.xml file and detailed error messages it's hard to guess what's the problem is. Furthermore i would recommend to test the build first on command line if it works without any failure.

Answer (score 3):

After reading your question, I can't find any relationship with your title.

Anyway, you may try right click on your project, and choose `Maven` -> `Update Dependencies` or `Update Project Configuration`.  Sometimes changes in projects (especially manual change) requires manual refresh to make M2E plugin aware of your change and synchronize Eclipse project for you.

Such issue can cause maven install works (because it read directly from POM and perform the build), but Eclipse doesn't (because it build base on the Eclipse project generated by M2E plugin)

Comment: Oh. It seems that I need to make it a "Maven" project but not "Spring" project. Thanks.

Comment: As suggested by kmarbaise in comment, I believe you have no understanding in Maven?  I will suggest you take a look in Maven, create some projects and try it out IN THE COMMAND LINE first.  Get yourself used to and understand the convention and idea of Maven first

Comment: What I don't understand is that although they've managed to make an integration to eclipse, which enabled "point and click" usage of it, the result is not expected. So I wonder if Maven was designed as command line tool, then the eclipse integration could be a bad one, given that it doesn't give much clue for the failure. So there is the question in the title.

Comment: Yes, Maven is developed as a command line build tools, though it also provide library for embedding in other app (like Eclipse).  Whether the integration is bad or not have nothing to do with whether it is a command line tools.  I believe you didn't even get yourself familiar with basic concepts of Maven, as you seems even not turning on Maven support in your original project.  And, Maven is not a complement to Eclipse, you can't just expect it to work so transparently when you are working in Eclipse